# What is the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{1+ks^{\alpha}}$?

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

What is the inverse Laplace transform of F(s)=$\frac{1}{1+ks^{\alpha}}$, $k$ is the constant and $\alpha$ is another constant. Especially when $\alpha$ is not an integer.

Comment: Mathematica didn't give any results, so it's unlikely that there's any nice closed form for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CAS help:

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{1+k s^{\alpha }}\right](t)=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^j k^{-1-j}
   t^{-1+\alpha +j \alpha }}{\Gamma (\alpha +j \alpha )}=\frac{t^{-1+\alpha } E_{\alpha ,\alpha
   }\left(-\frac{t^{\alpha }}{k}\right)}{k}$$

where: $E_{\alpha ,\alpha }\left(-\frac{t^{\alpha }}{k}\right)$ is  generalized [Mittag-Leffler](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mittag-LefflerFunction.html) function.

Generalization:

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{a+k s^{\alpha }}\right](t)=\frac{t^{-1+\alpha } E_{\alpha ,\alpha }\left(-\frac{a
   t^{\alpha }}{k}\right)}{k}$$